# How can I pass ssh public key when starting IBM containers?

Tags: ibm-cloud

The follwing document says I can pass ssh public key by --ssh option of 'cf ic run' command: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/container_cli_ov.html

But the command shows error message:

```
$ cf ic run --ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys -p 22 registry.ng.bluemix.net/ruimo/pgsql944-cli
flag provided but not defined: --ssh
See 'docker run --help'.

Invalid IBM-Containers commands or docker commands.
Available IBM Containers commands are {login, group, ip, route, volume, namespace, info}
In addition, IBM Containers supports native docker cli passthrough, run cf ic help for more details
```

How can I pass ssh public key?

```
Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
$ cf --version
cf version 6.12.0-8c65bbd-2015-06-30T00:10:31+00:00

$ cf plugins
Listing Installed Plugins...
OK

Plugin name      Version   Command name   Command Help
IBM-Containers   0.8.598   ic             IBM-Containers Plugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "IBM-Containers" Cloud Foundry CLI plugin is still in active development. It appears there are issues with the documentation referring to features that haven't been finished.

As a workaround, you can use the standalone "ICE" tool to import SSH keys into running containers.

```
$ ice run --ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys -p 22 registry.ng.bluemix.net/ruimo/pgsql944-cli
```